# SharePoint Modern Team Site Top Navigation Bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site, modern

I love the new SharePoint Modern experience except for **one** thing.

My **Communication Site** has a top navigation menu underneath the Title:
[image: Communications Site Navigation]

My **Team Site** has it above the Title, floated to the left, past the logo. How do I change this to match the Communications Site:
[image: Team Site Navigation]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online modern team sites, you can only use SPFx extensions to customize the top navigation bar.

You can refer to the [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss) to inject CSS or [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) with CSS.